# Choosing a category in dropdown and inserting a vlue using textbox

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Hi My problem is how to insert a value using a text box.

First the admin need to choose a category example.
A cellphone Brand. The admin will choose a cellphone brand using Drop down list and then after choosing a brand it will input the cellphone model using text box and click the button save and then the model brand will store in database.

Please help me. If there's any tutorial please tell me.
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Where's your blueprint?

Comment: @RiteshA I haven't tried anything

Answer (score 0):

If you use php and look around on the web about mysql, you should get your answer.